# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: jmeter

How to resolve javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error when using jmeter through GUI mode. I have changed the https.default.protocol=SSLv3 in jmeter.properties file but i am still not able to resolve it. Pls advice.

Comment: what version of jmeter are you using and what version of Java ?

Comment: i am using Jmeter 2.13 and java version 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the full stacktrace ?

Read from:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

This:

> You may encounter the following error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints if you run a HTTPS request on a web site with a SSL certificate (itself or one of SSL certificates in its chain of trust) with a signature algorithm using MD2 (like md2WithRSAEncryption) or with a SSL certificate with a size lower than 1024 bits.
>   This error is related to increased security in Java 7 version u16 (MD2) and version u40 (Certificate size lower than 1024 bits), and Java 8 too.
>   To allow you to perform your HTTPS request, you can downgrade the security of your Java installation by editing the Java jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms property. Remove the MD2 value or the constraint on size, depending on your case.
>   This property is in this file:

- JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security

Although you don't have the same exception that might be your issue, that's why I need full stacktrace